# Language to Write Site to Accept Bitcoin

Tags: payment, bitcoin

You can't write secure sites with Java because the source code can be examined, does PHP fix this problem?  What should I pick up and look to to find out how to write a web server that can handle payments, like with Bitcoin or an0ther protocol?

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Don't rely on difficulty of reverse-engineering to maintain security.

- Every language can be reverse-engineered, whether it produces native assembly code, Java byte code or is a scripting language such as PHP or Javascript. The final product of any coding language, whether script or byte code, can usually be obfuscated to make attempts at reverse-engineering more difficult **BUT REVERSE-ENGINEERING WILL NEVER BE IMPOSSIBLE**.

### 2. Don't rely on obscurity of source code to maintain security.

- How difficult a language is to reverse-engineer, however, holds no bearing on whether that makes it a good or bad candidate for programming a web server. As long as your server is secure, your server code will not leak out.
- Best practices dictate that your server security should not rely on any secrets in your code. Even if your code were to leak out and be accessible by the public, it should not affect the security of your web server ***as long as it is properly coded*** (no secrets stored in code and no vulnerabilities).
- Your secrets, such as password hashes, should be stored in a shared (shared between instances of your web server) database or some other form of shared secure storage.
- In some cases, your code may contain vulnerabilities, and exposing the code to the public may reveal these vulnerabilities. This is generally considered A Good Thing. Whether or not vulnerabilities are known to the public, they will still exist until they are fixed in the code. Public review helps to identify these vulnerabilities early on (allowing them to be fixed and the vulnerabilities eliminated) instead of allowing them to be surreptitiously exploited.

### 3. Combine IT best practices with coding best practices to create and maintain a secure server.

- Maintaining a secure server requires not only wise coding but wise IT practices. Ultimately, selecting the best language for a web server should be more a case of selecting the best tool for the job, or the one you are most comfortable with.

Consider posting security questions to https://security.stackexchange.com/